# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "order[message]" that is not disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my spec.rb test file `fill_in "order[message]", with: "Don't eat paint chips!"`
is failing with this error.

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find field "order[message]" that is not disabled
```

Here is my html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @order, url: "/gift/orders", local: true  do |form| %> 
  .
  .
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <%= form.label :message, "Note for the child" %>
      <%= form.text_field :message, class: "form-control", :rows => "3" %>
      <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
        Optional
      </small>
  </div> 
  .
  .
<% end %>
```

Any ideas why my test cannot read the form element?

Comment: Is there something that I would need to add to the message model or an rspec config?